# Kinematics: rest and motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

A ball is dropped from a height of 19.6 m above the ground. It rebounds from the ground and raises itself up to the same height. Take the starting point is the origin and vertically downward as the positie X-axis. Draw approximate plots of a versus t graph. Neglect the small interval during which the ball was in contact with the ground;The acceleration changes from 9.8m/s2 to -9.8m/s2, but answer given in my reference book H C Verma pg:44 shows a straight line drawn in +ve axis and a small gap at t=2 . it is wrong right?

Comment: Hi @Angeline varghese. Welcome to PSE. Please note that "homework-type" questions are considered off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

The acceleration points downwards when the object is moving freely, no matter if rising or falling (its gravity what accelerates it, and gravity points to the ground, doesn't it?) The only time when acceleration is not $g$ is when the object is not falling/rising freely, this is when it is in contact with the ground.

Comment: But when a body falls freely under the action of gravity , the velocity increases and the value of g is taken positive and when a body is thrown  vertically upward , its velocity decreases and the value of g is taken as negative

Comment: That's only because your are changing the direction of your axis in the middle of the exercise, which in my opinion its confusing. If I were you, I would choose some +/- directions for the x-axis before doing anything (say, positive downwards) and keep that convention both for the fall and the rise.

Comment: So is it correct to say that g cannot be -9.8m/s2 ? Is it that what you were trying to say that g is always downwards meaning g=9.8m/s2

Comment: @Angelinevarghese Yes, when any object is falling under gravity near the surface of the earth, its acceleration is $g=9.8$ m/s/s downwards. The *velocity* of the ball changes sign when it bounces off the ground, but its acceleration does not change.

Comment: But the direction of acceleration changes right? so we should also plot the graph in 4th qudrant right?

Comment: no, both magnitude and direction of acceleracion are always the same (neglecting the small time interval when the ball is in contact with the ground). The magnitude is $9.8 m/s$ and the direction is "downwards"(towards the center of the Earth.)

Comment: Even the sign of  acceleration wont change ?

Comment: If you take the x axis to be always positive downwards, the acceleration will be always positive.